# How to find the source of a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, lldb

I am running my app in the simulator, and after a few interactions with the screen, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The `bt` shows the following:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x64a4, 0x021a80be libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 26, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xeea812b8)
    frame #0: 0x021a80be libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 26
    frame #1: 0x002b7c37 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 743
    frame #2: 0x00792c3b CoreGraphics`data_provider_finalize + 51
    frame #3: 0x002b7bdc CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 652
    frame #4: 0x0086a504 CoreGraphics`image_finalize + 96
    frame #5: 0x002b7bdc CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 652
    frame #6: 0x049822a0 QuartzCore`CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 20
    frame #7: 0x0498230e QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::unlock() + 54
    frame #8: 0x04a2097a QuartzCore`CA::Layer::free_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 168
    frame #9: 0x04982825 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 545
    frame #10: 0x04982e58 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
    frame #11: 0x0031a9de CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    frame #12: 0x0031a920 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    frame #13: 0x0031035a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    frame #14: 0x0030fbcb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    frame #15: 0x0030f9fb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #16: 0x0455d24f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #17: 0x0455d08c GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #18: 0x00fcb8b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
  * frame #19: 0x001006cf APPNAME`main [inlined] top_level_code + 76 at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #20: 0x00100683 APPNAME`main + 35 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #21: 0x02912ac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

If I ask for `f 19`, I get the following, which is not very helpful:

```
frame #19: 0x001006cf APPNAME`main [inlined] top_level_code + 76 at AppDelegate.swift:12
   9    import UIKit
   10   
   11   @UIApplicationMain
-> 12   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
   13   
   14       var window: UIWindow?
   15
```

Using my screen in a different way, now I got the following `bt`:

```
* thread #6: tid = 0x7d08, 0x021f65ef libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_trap() + 3, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-qos', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x021f65ef libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_trap() + 3
    frame #1: 0x021f6676 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_fatal + 99
    frame #2: 0x0220cc74 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::busted(bool) + 152
    frame #3: 0x0220ba9f libobjc.A.dylib`objc_autoreleasePoolPush + 43
    frame #4: 0x02930f53 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190
    frame #5: 0x0293284a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 115
    frame #6: 0x02ca4296 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 724
    frame #7: 0x02ca1eea libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 30
```

I have tried cleaning my project, as suggested in another question, and the error still happens. I am new to iOS programming, and to lldb, and don't have a clue where to look next.

Comment: A common source of this sort of problem is a dangling pointer to some deallocated object. I'd suggest temporarily modifying your scheme and turning on zombies. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html

Comment: @Rob: Thank you! It seems I was using a stale `dispatch_queue_t` that had been obtained by `dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)`. I am surprised about this because my object holds a reference to it. Getting it again seems to solve the problem.